# padding in the Header or P tag doesn't work correctly with em unit

Tags: html, css

I have a problem when using the `em` unit for padding.
I have a div with a `h5` tag

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <h5>
        my header
    </h5>
</div>
```

and with this CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


#myDiv{
    font-size: 32px;
}

 #myDiv h5{
        background-color: red;
        color: white;
        padding: 1em;
    }
```

I should expect the padding to be equivalent to 32px but when I open Inspect on the browser
I see padding calculated to the below image

[image]

padding size is 13.280px

but when I use div or section instead of h5 that work fine.

Comment: What is the font size set on the h5 element itself?

Comment: @dantheman font-size is not set for h5. just set for parent div

Comment: `em` depends on the font-size of the element that it is on. By default, `div` and `section` tags have a default font size of 16px. An `h5` has a font size of 13.28 px by default. [Source](http://zuga.net/articles/html-heading-elements/#:~:text=h5%20%3D%200.83em%2F13.28px&text=Normal%20text%20height%20is%201em%20%2F%2016px.).

Use h4 instead (it has a default of 16px)

Comment: @HasanCheraghi The h5 element will have a default browser size on it own. Try adding `font-size: inherit` to the h5.

Comment: @BernardBorg thank you bro for your clear answer. I thought If we don't set `font-size` in h5, padding depends on the first parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`em` depends on the `font-size` of the element that it is on. This means that if you have the following;

```css
.example {
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 4em;
}
```

then the padding would be 80px.

By default, div and section tags have a default font size of 16px. An h5 has a font size of 13.28 px by default. Source. Use h4 instead (it has a default of 16px) or set the h5's font-size to 16px.

```css
#myDiv h5{
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 1em;
}
```

NOTE: These values might differ slightly between browsers.

You can see this in action here;

```js
let h1 = document.querySelector("h1");
let div = document.querySelector("div");
let section = document.querySelector("section");
let h5 = document.querySelector("h5");
let h4 = document.querySelector("h4");

console.table({ "h1": window.getComputedStyle(h1).getPropertyValue('font-size'), "div": window.getComputedStyle(div).getPropertyValue('font-size'), "section": window.getComputedStyle(section).getPropertyValue('font-size'), "h5": window.getComputedStyle(h5).getPropertyValue('font-size'), "h4": window.getComputedStyle(h4).getPropertyValue('font-size') });
```

```html
<h1>Hi</h1>
<div>Hi</div>
<section>Hi</section>
<h5>Hi</h5>
<h4>Hi</h4>
```